# How to re-initialize weights of pre-trained model with Glorot on Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to re-initialice layers weights using Glorot Uniform with Keras from Tensorflow. The closest approach is this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
for layer in base_model.layers:
  layer_new_weights = []
  for layer_weights in layer.get_weights():
    initializer = tf.compat.v1.keras.initializers.glorot_normal
    weights = initializer(np.shape(layer_weights))
    layer_new_weights .append(weights)
  layer.set_wegiths(layer_new_weights)
```

Any idea how to really set weights initializing from Glorot Uniform each layer of pretrained model as ResNet50?

Thanks!

Comment: This code seems to do exactly what you want, what is the problem?

Comment: Doesn't works. Weights results to be `GlorotNorm`

Comment: Can you be specific? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You could publish the output for which you believe it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution with less code is the following:

```
init = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform()
for w in model.trainable_variables:
    w.assign(init(w.shape))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing that on keras.applications.xception or other keras transfer learning model. Try this: `InceptionV3(input_shape = (150, 150, 3), include_top = False, weights=None)`By setting the weights to None(Random initialization), mabye you can get your "re-initialized" pretrained model. Glorot doesn't seem to work for all layers in Resnet.